# Test GrapesJs Editor With Cypress

Tags: cypress, grapesjs

We are using grapesjs to create an application editor. We want to validate that all the components we create can be used in Grapesjs. To do it, we want to write e2e tests using UI to simulate a final user. I'm using Cypress for automation but didn't have any luck dropping block inside the grapes iframe. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far, failing that the HTML of the app - or both.

Answer (score 0):

Me and my coworker tryied for 2 weeks, both Cypress and the rest of the tools on the market couldn't drag and drop a block of GrapesJs inside it's iframe :/

You can follow the issue from GrapesJs: https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/3721

And a discussion i opened in Cypress's repo:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/17979

Last month, i find this option, but i didn't try to set it as false on grapesjs.init, can you test it?

https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/blob/dev/src/editor/config/config.js#L111